# Handling errors with .subscribe()

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I use rxjs5 beta to load images and do other stuff. But, I can not understand why `.subscribe()` can't handle 404 errors. Is it because events can't fail? Here is my code:

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = 'http://some.file/that/does/not-exist.jpg';

var sourceLoad = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(image, 'load');
var sourceError = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(image, 'error');

sourceLoad.subscribe(
  function(e) { 
    console.log('loaded');
  }/*,
  function(e) {
    console.log('Handling errors here is not working. Why?')
  }
  */
);


sourceError.subscribe(
  function(e) { 
    console.log('error');
  }
);
```

Comment: Maybe you're not getting an error? And, I hestitate to even mention this, but maybe because the error handler is commented out? And keep in mind, that `sourceError` subscriber is not actually logging errors, but successes. The second parameter to the subscribe function is the error handler.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var sourceLoad = Rx.Observable.from([1,2]).map(x => throw 'error here')
sourceLoad.subscribe(
    x => console.log('A OK'),
    err => console.log(err)
)
```

ES5 fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/jkennaly/7r3jgbhs/